# $\sin x \left(\cos \frac{1}{2x}\right) = ( \sin x)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> $$\sin x \left(\cos \frac{1}{2x}\right) = (\sin x)^2$$

I thought it will be :

$$ (\cos \frac{1}{2x}) = (\sin x)$$

Because just like $ ab = a^2$ then $b=a$

But it is

$$\sin x (\cos \frac{1}{2x})-(\sin x)^2 =0$$

Why?

Comment: $ab=a^2$ implies $b=a$ or $a=0$ since $0(b)=0^2$ is true and $a(a)=a^2$ is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like $ab=a^2$ you cannot divide by a unless you know it is nonzero. In this case it is the same, $a=0$ is one solution, and

$\sin(x)=0$

is a solution to your problem. Dividing out the sin removes it as a solution which you don’t want to do. Now, you can either solve it as a quadratic like you have posted, or simply take into account that when you divide by sin, you must account for when it is zero.